# Show that every prime ideal of A (UFD) is generated by a set of prime elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, unique-factorization-domains

Considering A as a unique factorization domain, we must show that every prime ideal of A is generated by a set of prime elements. I was able to do it for a principal prime ideal, but I couldn't do it for other cases.

Comment: This is a classic characterization of a UFD - see the theorem in my answer in the dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an element f of the prime ideal and factor it as a product of prime elements in the UFD A. Since the ideal is prime, one factor must actually belong to the ideal and collecting these elements as f runs through the ideal gives you a generating set as desired.

Note that the case of a principal ideal is the very definition of being prime: an element is a prime element if and only if the principal ideal generated by it is prime.